# Model is always null when date-time field is serialized in C# - Restsharp

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, restsharp

I am having an issue with simple serialization and deserialization in C#.

I am using RestSharp to call a webapi method (REST method).

**Model is:**

```
public class MyModel
{
  public DateTime date {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller Method:**

```
[RoutePrefix("Test")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/Date")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] MyModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
          return NotOk();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, the `model` is always null when using `xml`.

**Restsharp Client:**

```
var restRequest = new RestRequest(@"http://localhost:50099/Date", Method.POST)
{
      RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml,
};

restRequest.AddBody(new MyModel(), "");
```

----> when data format is `xml`, the model is  null.

**Restsharp Client:**

```
var restRequest = new RestRequest(@"http://localhost:50099/Date", Method.POST)
{
      RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
};

restRequest.AddBody(new MyModel(), "");
```

-----> when data format is json, the model is not null. The date property is default.

Comment: Have you run fiddler(network) trace on the request?  - it would be interesting to see the headers in the request and what the 'content-type' is set to.

Comment: I checked. the `content-type` is set to `text/xml`

Comment: and can you show us what the posted xml looks like from the trace ?

Comment: `<MyModel>/r/n <Date>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM </Date> /r/n </MyModel>`

Comment: Take a look at this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052280/how-to-post-xml-using-fiddler-to-asp-net-webapi) looks like a similar problem that's resolved by fully specifying the xml namespaces ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033514/model-binding-is-always-null-in-webapi/26057183#26057183).

In short, I set `DataContractSerializer` to be true while initializing `Json serializer`. This `DataContractSerializer` expected date in `epoch` format and hence the issue.