# Asp.Net Web Api, how to get posted XML format data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I use `var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` to get that data posted to mine is

```
<xml><OpenId><![CDATA[oX2XXXXXX-HFCR8O_BkI]]></OpenId>
<AppId><![CDATA[wxbcXXXXXX4d]]></AppId>
<IsSubscribe>0</IsSubscribe>
<ProductId><![CDATA[XXXXXX01]]></ProductId>
<TimeStamp>1416482878</TimeStamp>
<NonceStr><![CDATA[XXXXXXX]]></NonceStr>
<AppSignature><![CDATA[cff4XXXXXX8a513891f0]]></AppSignature>
<SignMethod><![CDATA[sha1]]></SignMethod>
</xml>
```

And I've crated the structure

```
public class PackageModal
    {
        public string OpenId { get; set; }
        public string AppId { get; set; }
        public string IsSubscribe { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public string NonceStr { get; set; }
        public string AppSignature { get; set; }
        public string SignMethod { get; set; }
    }
```

But in the controller, 
[HttpPost]

```
public string PostNotify(PackageModal modal)
{
 ....
}
```

Why the `modal` is null?  Do I need to specify that posted data is XML-format?

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142702/aspnet-webapi-post-parameter-is-null-when-sending-xml . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052280/how-to-post-xml-using-fiddler-to-asp-net-webapi

Comment: @Kumar That answer recommended setting the global config. But I only need this specific api to receive XML data

Answer (score 0):

What about if you sent a JSON instead of XML, will that work ?

if not, try use [FromBody] in your method, so something like

```
public string PostNotify([FromBody]PackageModal modal)
{
 ....
}
```

This will tell the model binder to try map the PackageModel from the request body.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `[FromBody]` Not working. The api is a payment notify url. I can't decide to receive other than the xml format data.

Comment: Yeah,  but how will you client send the xml.? As a query string (in the url) or in the message body?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public string ReturnXmlDocument(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
    return doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
}
```

That's it!